# Are there any guidelines to write a format of a file in a document in LaTeX?

Tags: typography

Some times I have to cite in my writings some file format using the "dot notation" e.g. `.tiff` or `.dll`.

So far I am using these formats:

```
\verb|.dll|
\textit{.dll}
```

Any guidelines or recommendation from the typography and publishing industry I am not aware of?

Comment: Well... [CMS](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/InternetWebandOtherPost-WatergateConcerns.html)

Comment: You can use the \path command from [url.sty](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/url/), which offers the advantages that it is some kind of a standard, that it can do some reasonable line-breaking if you need that, and that you could change the definition later if a publisher wants something different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general I think that a typewriter font is used for "computer code" but particular publishers (or thesis style checkers) may differ. I would use either `\verb|.tag|` or preferably `\texttt{.tag}`. Others may well disagree.

Answer (score 1):

- **In my understanding, the dot is *not* part of the filename extension.** (See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_filename_extensions) for example.)
- If a file is named `Letter.txt` for example, then the filename extension is `txt`.
- Therefore, I would classify the file as a `TXT`-file or `txt`-file using `\texttt{}`.

> [...] usually the extension is the substring which follows the last
>   occurrence, if any, of the dot character [...]